# Stacking multiple barchart subplots into one PDF (python, matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, subplot

I'm struggling hard with subplot madness. I've made a bunch of bar charts, which I want to save to one PDF in sequence. Each of which summarizes a binary variable (usually stacked, but unstacked is ok if it's simpler). The charts are fine, but when I try fitting them into a grid of subplots I muck it up!

My problems are 1) I'm not iterating through the data properly, and 2) I can't seem to stack one column of charts--only works with 2+.

Sorry for such a lame question, but this is the closest I've gotten! Any suggestions?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100, 12)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKL')) #load data
key_vars = list('ABCDEFGH') #variables to plot
num_plots = len(key_vars) #number of subplots

fig, ax = plt.subplots(num_plots, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row') #create figure

for i in range(num_plots):
    for j in range(2):
        ax[i,j].barh(df[key_vars[i]].value_counts(),10) #create subplots

fig.savefig('binary_barcharts.pdf') #save to .pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
(df[key_vars].apply(pd.Series.value_counts
   .T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is not a bad solution. I like that it's simple and clean. Although I'm still trying to get the plots into separate subplots.